# How to load this dataset into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data)

I tried reading the pandas.read_csv doc to see how I could use newlines to delimit each row as a separate sample. Which parameter should I use to do this?

Comment: "use newlines to delimit each row " that happens automatically. I'm not sure what you want to do differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read it right in with `pd.read_csv`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data', header=None)
```